# Unable to click on a certain tab in a webpage

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've been trying to click on a ceratin tab located just above the headers of a big table. That very tab is named and visible as ***`Pitchers`***. Where I'm going wrong?

[website link](https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/stats.php)

This is the script I'm trying with:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto('https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/stats.php');
    await page.waitForSelector("div[data-name='p']");
    const elem = await page.$("div[data-name='p']");
    await elem.click();
    // await browser.close();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('the error: ', e);
  }
})();
```

The error it encounters:

```
TimeoutError: waiting for selector "div[data-name='p']" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
```

> How can I get click on the `Pitchers` tab in that webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That selector is case-sensitive. This should work:

```js
await page.waitForSelector("div[data-name='P']");
const elem = await page.$("div[data-name='P']");
```

Using the [case-insensitive selector](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-case-insensitive) should also work:

```js
await page.waitForSelector("div[data-name='P' i]");
const elem = await page.$("div[data-name='P' i]");
```